# jest react-testing-library error symbol is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

Hello everyone i have problem with simple test i try test has text in Link tag and has link tag in nav but i see error symbol is not a function can you help me please?

my test code:

```
const mockUseLocationValue = {
    pathname: "",
    search: '',
    hash: '',
    state: null
}
jest.mock('react-router', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual("react-router") as {},
    useLocation: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return mockUseLocationValue;
    })
}));

test("should render the home page", () => {
    render(<Header />);
    const navbar = screen.getByTestId("navbar");
    const link = screen.getByTestId("home-link");
    expect(link.innerHTML).toMatch("Home page");
    expect(navbar).toContainElement(link);
});
```

My original code:

```
export const Header = ():JSX.Element => {
    const location = useLocation()
    const { pathname } = location
    const splitLocation = pathname.split('/')
    return (
        <HeaderBlock as='h3' block>
            <nav data-testid="navbar">
                <ul className={styles.links}>
                    <li>
                        <Link data-testid="home-link" to="/">
                            Home Page
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </HeaderBlock>
    )
}
```

Comment: Why are you mocking the code you are trying to test? The RTL testing functions can take a `wrapper` option... you should use this to wrap the component being tested inside a router component.

Comment: @DrewReese i start learning testing without mocking i see error location is undefined can you show please how fix error please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `react-testing-library` you can specify additional options for the `render` function, one of them being a `wrapper`.

[wrapper](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#wrapper)

> Pass a React Component as the `wrapper` option to have it rendered
> around the inner element. This is most useful for creating reusable
> custom render functions for common data providers.

You shouldn't mock functionality you are testing.

Create a memory router for testing in jest.

```
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

export const RouterWrapper = ({ children }) => (
  <MemoryRouter>{children}</MemoryRouter>
);
```

In test, import the wrapper and pass in the options.

```
import { RouterWrapper } from '../path/to/test/util';

test("should render the home page", () => {
  render(
    <Header />,
    {
      wrapper: RouterWrapper
    }
  );

  const navbar = screen.getByTestId("navbar");
  const link = screen.getByTestId("home-link");

  expect(link.innerHTML).toMatch("Home page");
  expect(navbar).toContainElement(link);
});
```

Comment: thanks for help but error is the same symbol is not a function

Comment: @NikitaKagan can you add the full error message to your question, and any stacktrace if it's available?

Comment: @NikitaKagan I see. If you comment out the queries and expect statements so you are just running the render do you have the issue? Does the issue occur when querying?

Comment: yes problem in render i comment last four lines of code

Comment: @NikitaKagan Is that your full `Header` component code? It seems incomplete, i.e. `splitLocation` isn't used. What happens if you comment out all the JSX in `Header`  and render just the outer `HeaderBlock` component and run the test?

Comment: https://dpaste.org/A1U4 the full code i use splitLocation for use activeRoute